# How is a prefix sum a bulk-synchronous algorithmic primitive?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Concerning NVIDIA GPU the author in [High Performance and Scalable GPU Graph Traversal](https://5d3c0b13-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/duanemerrill/BFS_TR.pdf?attachauth=ANoY7crVHY9WzhpW2K7XWKg4pPKaFofg-USYEJi1zHPxMi-aAjNBxUXLijYw_xW4KB29zOZEieH6kl4c3d7kgKnUFd13CcqgKIK5u141CJb2W-2VbhW-frVrkBKz4hyu7iNx791wO0UuwvJ8CdhtQ0OKMHLLTWmmbX2tBh1JDflGVdLPYqJ6q3_ToFdFg4VDBoIe8xN5J802k_BKQB1YZbMDOWjf878H8Q==&attredirects=0) paper says:

> 1-A sequence of kernel invocations is bulk- synchronous: each kernel is
>   initially presented with a consistent view of the results from the
>   previous.
>
> 2-Prefix-sum is a bulk-synchronous algorithmic primitive

I am unable to understand these two points (I know GPU based prefix sum though), Can smeone help me this concept.

Answer (score 2):

> 1-A sequence of kernel invocations is bulk- synchronous: each kernel is initially presented with a consistent view of the results from the previous.

It's about parallel computation model: each processor has its own memory which is fast (like cache in CPU) and is performing computation using values stored there without any synchronization. Then non-blocking synchronization takes place - processor puts data it has computed so far and gets data from its neighbours. Then there's another synchronization - barrier, which makes all of them wait for each other.

> 2-Prefix-sum is a bulk-synchronous algorithmic primitive

I believe that's about the second step of BSP model - synchronization. That's the way processors store and get data for the next step.

Name of the model implies that it is highly concurrent (many many processes that work synchronously relatively to each other). And this is how we get to the second point.

As far as we want to live up to the name (be highly concurrent) we want get rid of sequential parts where it is possible. We can achieve that with prefix-sum.

Consider prefix-sum associative operator `+`. Then scan on set `[5 2 0 3 1]` returns the set `[0 5 7 7 10 11]`. So, now we can replace such sequential pseudocode:

```
foreach i = 1...n
    foo[i] = foo[i-1] + bar(i);
```

with this pseudocode, which now can be parallel(!):

```
foreach(i)
    baz[i] = bar(i);
scan(foo, baz);
```

That is very much naive version, but it's okay for explanation.

Comment: @gpuguy - it's local (for processor) part of data. I hope I got your question right

Comment: So you mean bulk means there are many many synchronizations taking place? bulk= many many? Also really appreciate if you can elaborate point no 2 a little more.

Comment: @gpuguy, yes, practically. I'll update answer as it's too long for comment.

Comment: Yes, I think you can make a a little detailed answer. Thanks

Comment: @gpuguy updated answer with basic explanation. If it's still too vague - let me know, I'm just trying not to go into complex formulae and diagrams, which make those terms seem hard to grasp, when they are really self-explanatory and not so complex.

Comment: Now things are much clear , except baz[i] = bar(i); why it is required?

Comment: @gpuguy you still need an element of set to produce scan. The point is that now you don't need previous element, only next one and current sum.